# DBVisualizer Error : Long Message: SSL error: Connection reset, Details: Type: java.sql.SQLException SQL State: 08006

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I am getting below error while trying to connect to a Redshift database thru DB visualizer. It was working fine but then computer restarted and it stopped working. Now giving below error while connecting to Redshift -

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
SSL error: Connection reset

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLException
   SQL State: 08006
```